# Is there a way to apply the changes made from a merge in the past?

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge

I had to revert a merge into the master branch because the branch contained some unwanted changes. The branch however also contained a lot of changes that I need to revise. Is there a way to apply all of the changes that this merge added to the master into  my current branch and decide which of those changes i would like to stage and which ones to leave out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could rebase the branch with e.g. `rebase -i branch_root` then merge the new rebased branch; or `cherry-pick` onto a new branch, and again merge.

Comment: @Steve But how would that allow the OP to edit the merge?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The OP states that they've already reverted the merge. I guess my suggestion solves the problem in the post, but not really in the title?

Comment: I read that he wants to apply the merge again but then throw out some of the changes.  With a regular commit we could just use `git reset --soft`, but with a merge commit I'm afraid that wouldn't work.

Comment: The sentence I don't quite understand is *"The branch however also contained a lot of changes that I need to revise"*. Perhaps the solution is that we can `revert` individual commits from the merged branch.

Answer (score 0):

As always, you can either cherry-pick the merge, or revert the revert of the merge.  If you choose to cherry-pick the merge, you must supply a parent number, the same way you had to supply a parent number in order to revert the merge.

If you don't want the result to be committed, even if the cherry-pick or revert command succeeds on its own, you can tell the command not to do the commit step.  Or, you can allow the commit, then use `git reset --soft HEAD^` or `git reset --soft HEAD~1` to move the current branch back one step—almost the same as removing the commit itself—without altering the contents of the index and work-tree at all.

(I say "almost the same" because the commit continues to exist, and is protected for at least 30 days by default because its hash ID is stored in at least reflog entry.)

#### Alternatives

This may not be the wisest overall strategy, however.

Suppose you have something like this:

```
...--o--o-----*---------M--F--W--G--H   <-- mainline
         \             /
          A--B--C--D--E   <-- feature
```

where `M` is the bad merge, and `A--B--C--D--E` is the original chain of commits used to attempt to produce some feature.  Commit `W` is the revert of merge `M` (w is kind of an upside-down m) and there may have been various other commits as well, such as `F` through `H`.

What commit `M` is/does—besides of course being a merge—is that it makes changes to its *first* parent (`*`, above) based on the diff from the merge base parent of `A` to the last `feature` commit `E`.  So it introduces a big set of changes, and you've now discovered that the big set of changes is buggy.  Commit `W` introduces another big set of changes: those that exactly undo `M`.

If you now revert `W`, or cherry-pick `M`, you get another big set of changes.  If you do this without committing *yet* (or back it out), you can selectively apply or undo these changes by fussing about with your work-tree (perhaps using your index to do so, or just wholly manually) and then `git add`ing the revised big-set-of-changes and committing.  But that gives you another big lump of changes in your new commit `I`:

```
...--o--o-----*---------M--F--W--G--H--I   <-- mainline
         \             /
          A--B--C--D--E   <-- feature
```

The *last* time you added a big lump of changes, it was buggy.  Perhaps it would be a good idea to introduce the changes step-wise, one at a time, in such a way that each one is individually test-able, rather like the `A-B-C-D-E` sequence.

In fact, that very sequence is probably a good place to start.  Suppose you were to *copy* each commit in the `A-B-C-D-E` sequence to a *new* (but corrected) commit: `A'`, followed by `B'`, followed by `C'`, and so on.  If `A` itself is correct—if all the problems are in, say, `B` and later—copy it anyway:

```
                                      A'  <-- feature.1
                                     /
...--o--o-----*---------M--F--W--G--H   <-- mainline
         \             /
          A--B--C--D--E   <-- feature
```

Repeat for `B` through `E`:

```
                                      A'-B'-C'-D'-E'  <-- feature.1
                                     /
...--o--o-----*---------M--F--W--G--H   <-- mainline
         \             /
          A--B--C--D--E   <-- feature
```

and now you have a correct (and tested) revised feature branch, which you can merge as usual:

```
                                      A'-B'-C'-D'-E'  <-- feature.1
                                     /             \
...--o--o-----*---------M--F--W--G--H---------------M'   <-- mainline
         \             /
          A--B--C--D--E
```

Nothing special is required at this point, and the `feature.1` branch is fully bisectable to locate any *new* bugs in the newly-added feature that is related only by name and intent (but not commit hashes) to the originally-added, buggy feature.

In fact, now that you know about it, you've probably *already used* `git bisect` to *find* which of `A-B-C-D-E` introduced the bugs, so if you could just en-masse copy `A` through `E` to produce `A'` through `E'` (and not yet merge), then you could run `git rebase -i` and put in judicious `edit`s to fix them up, or use Git's auto-squash / auto-fixup features for this.

All you need is that "en masse copy" operation ... which, as it turns out, is *already built in to `git rebase`*, as the `--no-ff` option, as described [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt).